# Access 2010 query expression syntax help please

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm sure this is an elementary answer but I cannot see the forest for the trees at the moment, any help would be appreciated.

I'm building a query in which I need to have the results fill TRUE if there is any filled value in the table that is queried.

Comment: can you add some detail, table design etc, as that might help?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is that you convert the field your checking into a 1 or 0 based on whether it contains data or not.

So a table:

```
ID, Field1
1 , "A"
2 , ""
3 , "C"
```

You could then have a query:

```
SELECT Sum(IIf(Len(Trim([Field1]))>0,1,0)) AS CompletedFields FROM Table1;
```

Which will give you a count of the completed fields, in this case 2, which will equate to True as boolean.
Obviously you need to adjust the `Len(Trim([field]))>0` to match your rule that determines if a field is complete or not.

This also gives the actual number of completed (and therefore uncompleted) rows, rather than a blunt true/false.

Comment: :) I'd assumed that given a column in a table, you wanted to know if it was filled in or not?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain all of that although perhaps I wasn't clear about my question because I do not understand the answer. Inside of MS Access 2010, I have a query open in design view. In a new column, that I want to name MailPermission (after the result is gained), I'm actually using the field named AddressHomeLine1 and only if there is an address in that field do I want the result to be TRUE. From the examples I've found, the syntax might read: MailPermission: AddressHomeLine1 =IIF(AddressHomeLine1)= is not null then "True" else "false."

Comment: Almost right, try: `MailPermission: iif([AddressHomeLine1] is not null, true, false)`.  You might need a `and len(trim([AddressHomeLine1]))>0` after the null, in case the field contains a space etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot! I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I received a Syntax (comma) Error in query expression dialog box result

Comment: Thanks all. So I was able to gain an appropriate response to this query except that instead of TRUE or FALSE the result that is displayed is -1 or 0. How may I change this to reflect the TRUE or FALSE result requested?

Comment: Ok, crossed that hurdle'